# VisualSVN Server Migration from Windows 2008 to 2012 (Svn version 2.7.14)

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

We came to know that for moving svn server to new one, we can simply copy and paste the repos root location to new server.

so if we are replacing the root repository directory in the new server with the old server root data directory, Whether it will work as before, AD integration, the repo based authentication roles and all revision of each and every files ? Also the same work copy will work for the users if the same dns change happened to the target server from old serve ?

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT:** VisualSVN Server 2.7.x release family is **out of support** since January 15, 2016. This version does not receive patch or security updates and VisualSVN Team does not provide support for this version family. It is strongly recommended to upgrade your server instance to the latest version, **VisualSVN Server 3.9**. Please, read the article [KB138: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.9](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00138/) before beginning the upgrade. For the complete list of changes between version 2.7 and 3.9, take a look at the [changelog](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/).

Follow these steps to move your current VisualSVN Server 2.7.x instance to a new computer:

1. Run `svnadmin verify` against all of your source repositories to check them for corruptions. You can get more information on verifying repositories in [SVNBook | svnadmin verify](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/verify/) command line reference.
2. If all the repositories pass the verification successfully, on the new computer install the version of VisualSVN Server that is currently installed on the old computer. You can download VisualSVN Server 2.7.x from the [version 2.7 maintenance downloads page](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/2.7/).
3. Configure the new VisualSVN Server instance and move your repositories:

   - Stop VisualSVN Server services on the old and new computer before you begin copying the repositories to ensure that users don't make write operations while the copy is in progress.
   - Copy the repositories directly to the new server. You can copy the whole repositories root directory with all the repositories to the repositories root location on the new computer (e.g. from C:\Repositories on the old computer to C:\Repositories on the new computer). VisualSVN Server will pick up the copied repositories automatically when you place them to the repositories root location.
   - Start the VisualSVN Server services.

Don't forget to upgrade VisualSVN Server to the latest version after you complete the procedure!